# Powershell: Using Test-Path in combination with OlderThan. Could someone please take a look and tell me where my mistake is, thanks

Tags: powershell

I create a file in a folder.  Every 6 months the file needs updating.
I would like the script to tell me if the file is:

- less than 6 months old  (in Green)
- over 6 months old (yellow)
- file does not exist (red)

The current output I am getting is either red (does not exist)  or green (file is less than 6 months)

Even when the files is older than 6 months, it gives me the same output as green.

`PSVersion 5.1.19041.1682`

```
$playerID=$args[0]
$path = Test-Path O:\SPG\Gästedaten\*\*$playerID*\*KYC* -OlderThan(Get-Date).AddDays(-182)

if ($path -eq $false)
{
    Write-Host "This Guest has a VALID KYC. `n" -ForegroundColor Green
}
elseif ($path -eq $true)
{ 
    Write-Host "KYC is older than 6 months.`n" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
else
{
    Write-Host "Guest has no file or folder.`n" -ForegroundColor Red
}
```

Comment: Please [format your post properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). Use `\`\`\`` to fence code blocks.

Comment: What is ```$args[0]``` supposed to be doing? Where does it get a value.

Comment: is the file not in the same location every month, and does the name change? You are using wildcards in your path and special characters that need to be treated appropriately. You can also use `.AddMonths(-6)` method instead.

Comment: I assume there's only one result from test-path?

Comment: ```Test-Path``` returns ```$false``` if the path *does not exist*, so your ```Guest has no file or folder``` case is never reached. If the file doesn't exist at all it triggers the "This Guest has a VALID KYC" branch instead. You need to do two layers of checks: (i) does the file exist? (ii) *if it exists*, how old is it?

Comment: @dcaz  I manually enter the ID number.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala every guest has a different file, there are over a thousand.  The path and wildcards function correctly, the output is either "Yes the file exists" or "No file found"   Now I want to add whether or not the file is older than 6 months, it's this second part that does not function correctly.
I tried the AddMonths (-6) and still not working.

Comment: @mclayton Yes, it's that second layer of check that is giving me issues.  The first part functions correctly.

Comment: I think the *first* layer is giving you problems. If the file simply doesn't exist at all you're falling into the ```if ($path -eq $false)``` branch which says "This Guest has a VALID KYC.". Is that what you want / expect to happen? I.e. if there's no file at all (regardless of date) then the guest is valid?

Comment: @mclayton  It just gives me an error if it can't find the file, which is ok for me.  If the file is there, it gives me the correct output.     I'm sorry, I have no idea what I'm doing, I'm very new at this.

At first I just wanted to see if the file exists or not,   so i can make one if it doesnt exist.
Now i would like to add to it,  if the existing file is older than 6 months it needs to be renewed, hence the Green, Yellow and Red statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a lot to do with your script. I don't love `$arg[0]` but I don't know enough about what you are doing to help with that.

Please look at the comments in the script below and above.  Also please read
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules?view=powershell-7.2

https://stackoverflow.com/tour

```
$playerID = $args[0] 

#Check for the file and if not there stop everything.
$FileDate = $null
[date]$FileDate = Get-ChildItem -Path "O:\SPG\Gästedaten**$playerID**KYC*" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue | Select-Object CreationTime
IF ($null -eq $FileDate) {
    Write-Host "Guest has no file or folder.`n" -ForegroundColor Red
    break
}

#Test the file for 6 months or older
If ($filedate -ge (Get-Date).AddDays(-182)) {
    Write-Host "KYC is older than 6 months.n" -ForegroundColor Yellow
}
Else {
    
    # everything else is good
    Write-Host "This Guest has a VALID KYC. n" -ForegroundColor Green 
}
```

If you want the time to simply be greater then 6 month change `-ge` to `-gt`

---

I knew the `$arg[0]` was wrong. If this isn't correct below I am sorry to say I am not understanding or don't know.

```
#Check for the files and if not there stop everything.
$files = @{}
$Files = Get-ChildItem -Path Get-ChildItem -Path O:\SPG\*KYCReport*.pdf | Select-Object CreationTime, Name
IF ($null -eq $Files) {
    Write-Host "Guest has no file or folder." -ForegroundColor Red
    break
}

#loop through the files
$files | ForEach-Object {
    #Test the file for 6 months or older
    If ( (Get-Date).AddDays(-182) -ge $_.CreationTime) {
        Write-Host "KYC $($_.name) is older than 6 months." -ForegroundColor Yellow
    }
    Else {
    
        # everything else is good
        Write-Host "This Guest has a VALID KYC." -ForegroundColor Green 
    }
}
```

Comment: First I'd like to thank you for your time.
I have tried the script you posted but I can't seem to get it to work, I had no idea it would be this challenging for me.

I have a folder and inside there are many .pdf files named using this format: 133050KYCReport13.07.2022.pdf.  The number corresponds to a client.  If a number does not have a file, I must create one.   If the number has a file but is older than 6 months, I must create a new one.   If the file exists and is less than 6 months, I can move on to check the next number.

Comment: The current system in use is either clicking each folder manually or using the windows search.  But seeing that there are so many folders and files, it takes forever.
I wanted to create a script where I could open a shell terminal and type .\script.ps1 133050 and hit enter.  Then just hit the top arrow key, delete the 6 digit number and type the next number.

Comment: What is the folder structure ?  ```O:\SPG\Gästedaten\  random folder \ random folder \ *KYC*```

Comment: The line could be ```$files = Get-ChildItem -Path O:\SPG\Gästedaten\ -Recurse -File *KYC*  | Select-Object CreationTime, Name```

Comment: O:\SPG\Gästedaten\ A-Z one folder for each letter \ 123456 (guest ID) \the .pdf is in here *KYC*

Its very slow because it has to go through all the folders, but it works.

Comment: The recurse just made it super fast!!    Thank you so much for your time and patience!